# Magento 2: form & grid components on one page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, adminform

I want to create smth like this in adminhtml:

[image: UI sample]

This page contains form to type customer ID & grid to display downline data for the customer.

This is my description of the form component:

> ./view/adminhtml/ui_component/downline_select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">downline_select.downline_select_ds</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>

    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Bonus\Downline\Button\Get"/>
        </buttons>
        <!--<layout>-->
        <!--<type>tabs</type>-->
        <!--</layout>-->
        <deps>
            <dep>downline_select.downline_select_ds</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="downline_select_ds">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/form/provider/downline</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="module/downline/post"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\Module\App\Ui\DataProvider\Base"
                      name="downline_select_ds">
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="customer_select">
        <settings>
            <label></label>
        </settings>

        <field name="cust_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Customer ID</label>
                <dataScope>cust_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

    </fieldset>


    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">downline_grid</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>

</form>
```

The problem is that when I use:

```
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
```

the nested listing is displayed on the page but form data (Customer ID) is not saved on "Get Downline" action

> Magento_Ui/js/form/provider

```
    /**
     * Saves currently available data.
     *
     * @param {Object} [options] - Addtitional request options.
     * @returns {Provider} Chainable.
     */
    save: function (options) {
        var data = this.get('data');

        this.client.save(data, options);

        return this;
    },
```

`data` is undefined in `save()`.

But when I use

```
<settings>
    <layout>
        <type>tabs</type>
    </layout>
</settings>
```

in `./view/adminhtml/ui_component/downline_select.xml` and comment `templates/form/collapsible` I can get form data in `save()` but nested grid is not displayed. The error:

```
layout.js:404 Uncaught TypeError: container.insertChild is not a function
    at layout.js:404
    at Registry._resolveRequest (registry.js:418)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Registry._updateRequests (registry.js:400)
    at later (underscore.js:821)
```

is appeared in the browser when I load my page in adminhtml.

How can I use form and grid both in one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will work or not but you can try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="ui_form"/>
            <uiComponent name="ui_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I didn't try anything like this before but you should try once, please let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: oh great, I also learnt a new thing from this :)